# Объединение колонок в GRID

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-grid

Наткнулась на проблему с объединением GRID колонок.

[image: Пример]

Comment: приложи свой код

Answer (score 2):

Объединять ячейки можно через сокращения `grid-column`, `grid-row`.

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

div:nth-child(6) {
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
  background-color: black;
}

div:nth-child(7) {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.cell:nth-child(6) {
    grid-column: 2/5;
}
.cell:nth-child(7) {
    grid-area: 3/1/5/3;
}
```